# merge or concatenate map/array values to a new column based on condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks like this -

```
root
|-- query_results: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |  |-- result_type: string (nullable = true)
|    |  |-- title: string (nullable = true)
|    |  |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
|    |  |  |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |  |  |  |-- key: string (nullable = true)
|    |  |  |  |-- value: string (nullable = true)
|    |  |  |
```

The json data looks like this

```
{
  "root": {
    "queryresults": [
      {
        "title": "",
        "resulttype": "other",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "A",
            "value": "123"
          },
          {
            "key": "B",
            "value": "456"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "title",
        "resulttype": "answer",
        "attributes": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have multiple query_results in root and multiple attributes in query_results

I want to create a new column `titles` of type array which will depend on result_type, if `result_type == 'answer'` then pick `title` else pick value from attributes whose key == 'A' i.e "123"

Ex: `{"titles" : {"123", "title"}}`

There can be nulls in both title and attributes. In that case I want to skip picking any value.

I am trying trying to create a concatenated string initially and plan to convert it to array later but this ain't working.

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(aggregate(root.query_results,'', (a, item) -> concat(a,',', CASE WHEN item.resultType =='X' AND item.attributes IS NOT NULL THEN filter(item.attributes, x -> x.key = 'a')[0]["value"] ELSE item.title.s END )) as string) as titles")
```

Comment: what if result type is not 'x' and attributes' key is also not eq 'a'? also, please share a couple of sample records from a sample data for better understanding. my understanding is that you have multiple rows of struct (`query_result`) and want to convert them into an array.

Comment: the json seems malformed and does not match the schema you've shared.

Comment: I have updated it again.. The actual json and schema is much more complex. I have tried to simplify it according to the use case. Also I am new to pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the following input dataframe based on your sample json and schema

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|queryresults                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|[{other, , [{A, 123}, {B, 456}]}, {answer, title, []}]|
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

you can use `transform` function to iterate over each element of the array and `filter` function on attributes array field

```py
data_arr_sdf. \
    withColumn('titles', 
               func.expr('''
                         transform(queryresults, x -> if(x.result_type="answer", 
                                                         x.title, 
                                                         if(size(x.attributes)>0, 
                                                            filter(x.attributes, y -> y.key="A")[0].value, 
                                                            null
                                                            )
                                                          )
                                    )
                         ''')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------------------------------------------+------------+
# |queryresults                                          |titles      |
# +------------------------------------------------------+------------+
# |[{other, , [{A, 123}, {B, 456}]}, {answer, title, []}]|[123, title]|
# +------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```